# Word frequency with static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, int>>

Tags: c#, multithreading, linq, dictionary

**Hello,**

I wrote this function to count the vowels in a list full of words.

```
static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<char, int>> Sthmpa(string sourceItem)
{
     return sourceItem.ToLower()
                .Where(c => "aeiou".Contains(c))
                .GroupBy(c => c, (c, instances) => new KeyValuePair<char, int>(c, instances.Count()));
}
```

I want to change this return to count the words frequency in my list.

This is a list full of words.

```
static IList<string> lines = new List<string>();
```

Like this:

```
var g = lines.GroupBy(words=> words);
foreach (var grp in g)
{
     Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", grp.Key, grp.Count());
}
```

I print the word frequency, but I want to make this one like the same way I did with counting vowels.

Can anyone show how I can change?

To be clear, the function `Sthmpa` I am using in a thread function with `ConcurrentBag`...

Comment: How many words can there be in `lines`? Because the way you seem to be trying to solve this problem can have pretty serious performance issues.

Comment: I don't know in program how many words I have in lines, because I am taking them from some files. Maybe I can count them, but...

Comment: Is each line a word or can each line can have multiple words?

Comment: multiple words can have each line

Comment: You might want to throw a `.ToList()` on there before you return the data, every time you evaluate the returned `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<char, int>>` it will re-run the `Where` and `GroupBy`, by putting it to a `ToList()` before you return the result it will used the cached result during repeated uses.

Comment: can you write an example?

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
public IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, int>> GetWordFrequency(List<string> words)
{
    return words.GroupBy(w => w)
                .Select((item) => new KeyValuePair<string, int>(item.Key, item.Count()));
}
```

Comment: thank you! I guess this works fine, but I am using this function in another, and now I am getting the error with "cannot be inferred from the usage".... Anyway, thanks!

Comment: `Error 1 The type arguments for method 'ConsoleApplication1.Program.DoingAll<TSource,TKey,TValue,TResult>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, System.Func<TSource,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>>>, System.Func<System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<TKey,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TValue>>,TResult>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.`

Comment: Maybe the problem is with the third parameter of your method DoingAll. The second parameter matches with your method Sthmpa. But the third parameter match with a method that takes a KeyValuePair as parameter. Is that what you want?

Comment: i will try to post the 2nd function

Answer (score 0):

Here is my approach:

```
private IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, int>> GetOccurences(IEnumerable<string> words)
{
    return words.GroupBy(word => word, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
                .Select(group => new KeyValuePair<string, int>(group.Key, group.Count()))
                .OrderByDescending(kvp => kvp.Value);
}
```